# Wagner Parsifal ouverture, non fitting rhythyms

Tags: notation, rhythm

[image]
(click to enlarge image)

As a studying method I am making a reduction of Wagner's Parsifal ouverture.
In bar 3, the rhythm does not fit. The quarter, dotted eight, sixteenth and half note take up a sixteenth beat more space than there is.

I checked several sources, all have the dotted eight, so that is no mistake presumably.
What does this mean musically? And how should I notate it in Dorico, a program that forces correct rhythm?

Comment: Let's split each of those notes into 16ths. 1st = 4, dotted = 3, 1/16 = 1, minim = 8. That adds to 16.

Comment: You are adding wrong, as answer states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is one of those cases where staring at something too long makes the notes swim around on the page.  Happens to everyone sometimes! :D

A dotted eighth = 3/16, so that plus a sixteenth is a quarter.

Comment: It definitely was. Stared at it for an hour!

Comment: In college, I used to do my homework at a pub with great nachos, about 200 kinds of international beers, and a waitress I had a crush on.  Believe me, I had this experience VERY often! :D

Comment: When you stare at something for a long time, why might objects appear to move on the page? That is what might happen when you stare at music notation for a long time, try notating it in Dorico and face problems.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part of the question (though it's not actually needed here): the best way to input a bar with 'too many notes' in Dorico is to use hidden tuplets. That probably works for most other apps too.